# Datepicker range work wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

steps to reproduce:

1. Choose in 'to date' current day in footer (e.g Sunday, April 21, 2013)
2. Open 'from date' current link in disable

I need choose current day in 'from date', but I didn't do it. It's possible or this is bug?

I need the ability to select the current date from the link on the footer.

example change for start date control

```
 dateControlStart.bind('change', function (e) {
                var startDate = dateControlStart.value();

                if (startDate) {
                    startDate = new Date(startDate);
                    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
                    dateControlEnd.min(startDate);
                }
                else
                {
                    dateControlEnd.min(new Date(1753, 1, 1));
                }
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dude_jsfiddle/X2ZkQ/

Comment: please provide some more details??? issue is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the bug, and javascript date object by default take `00:00` hours so when you set max date for from calendar it set date `Apr 22,2013 00:00` (for PST current Date in Apr 22nd) so setting it for max date in from calendar it allows you only to select `Apr 21,2013 23:59:59` which disabled current date.

Try this for setting Max date:

```
   if (endDate) {
       endDate = new Date(endDate);
       endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate());
       endDate.setHours(23);
       dateControlStart.max(endDate);
   }
```

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/X2ZkQ/8/)